# How to set visiblity to a field group when a value of input is between 1 and 10

Tags: javascript, php

When the value in the "tds" field range between 1 to 10 below then the input "TAN" has appeared else it should in should not appear(hidden state)

```
<input id="tds" type="text" onchange="myFunction()"/>
<input  id="myP"  name="TAN" style="visibility:hidden;" value="test"/>
<script>
function myFunction() {
      tdsvalue = document.getElementById('tds').value;
        if (tdsvalue <= 10){
        document.getElementById("myP").style.visibility = "";
        else
        }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code i.e. improved version of yours:

```
    <input id="tds" type="text" onkeyup="myFunction(this)"/>
    <input  id="myP"  name="TAN" style="display:none;" value="test"/>
    <script>
    function myFunction(el) {
          var tdsvalue = el.value;
            if (tdsvalue >= 1 && tdsvalue <=10){
               document.getElementById("myP").style.display= "block";
            } else {
               document.getElementById("myP").style.display= "none";
            }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: You have reconstructed the function... this doesn't explain how or why this improves the current source code or explain anything about the original issue.

Comment: I didn't write a rocket science here. If you do not know that simple js code then you must ask google for it. New one to JS can easily figure out the changes I have made. Stackoverflow is not here for spoon feeding I assume

Comment: The point of asking why something isn't working is to explain the problem and then offer a solution. You don't need to be a rocket scientist to know that. I understand every line of your answer but for those who might not, a little bit of information would help.

Comment: Pleasure that it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Set `visibility` to `visible`, not `""`

And your code should look like this

```html
<input id="tds" type="text" onchange="myFunction()"/>
<input  id="myP"  name="TAN" style="visibility:hidden;" value="test"/>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  tdsvalue = document.getElementById('tds').value;
  if (tdsvalue <= 10) {
    document.getElementById("myP").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("myP").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
</script>
```

Note : You can also use `display:block` to show and `display:none` to hide.

`display:none` will not be available in the page and does not occupy any space. `visibility:hidden` hides an element, but it will still take up the same space as before. The element will be hidden, but still affect the layout.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a **syntax error** caused by `else`.

I would also recommend you parse the value as an integer using `parseInt()`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var tdsvalue = parseInt(document.getElementById('tds').value);
  if (tdsvalue <= 10) {
    document.getElementById("myP").style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myP").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="tds" type="text" onchange="myFunction()" />
<input id="myP" name="TAN" style="visibility:hidden;" value="test" />
```

If you have any questions about the source code above please leave a comment below and I will reply as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: If you are using == instead of === then `parseInt()` do not do any magic, it attempts to type cast the operand.